# Best way to upload/download a lot of images in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, background, xamarin

We're currently in the progress of developing a large enterprise application which needs to work offline. This means we need to load a lot of data in one set while the user waits.

Since the iPad app is used for legal purposes we need to upload/download images in full format. This means we can have about 50 images which are about ~10 mb.

We've been struggling to get this working and I need some advice and guidance into the right direction.

We are currently using the Background Transfer Service API.. for some reasons the application keeps forever syncing and doesn't stop.

Few questions:

1. Is it possible to start 50 tasks at the same time?
2. Should we download in batches? If so, what amount, 5 at a time?
3. What's the best NSURLSession configuration needed for this process?

I hope someone can help me into the right direction, because we've been stuck on this for a while!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could u share your code little  bit, then we could evaluate if there is a better solution ?

Comment: It's hard for me to share the code since it's embedded in some (legal) code. Basically what we've been using is the following: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_4_ios_backgrounding_walkthroughs/background_transfer_walkthrough/